# Where can i found Power Control Widget source android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Where can i found below link

```
07-26 11:32:31.865: VERBOSE/MAKIService(1081): Received Broadcast:android.intent.action.START_TETHER
07-26 11:32:31.865: VERBOSE/MAKIService(1081):         DataString:null
07-26 11:32:31.865: VERBOSE/MAKIService(1081):           toString:Intent { act=android.intent.action.START_TETHER }
```

I need to use this one for my bluetooth tether enabling .While pressing on the power widget tether button I observed this one on my log.Where can i found MAKIService?

At least give me code link of Power Control Widget.This will available from Android 1.6 onwards?

Answer (score 5):

This might be what you are looking for: [SettingsAppWidgetProvider.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/widget/SettingsAppWidgetProvider.java)